# What are the stash upgrades?

Tags: diablo-iii

What upgrades can you purchase for your shared stash? How much do they cost, and how many spaces do you gain from each one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your stash starts with One Tab that has 14 squares. It can be upgraded in 4 increments, unlocking another 14 squares, or 2 rows costing 10,000 gold per upgrade.

Once you have maxed your First Tab you can unlock a second tab for 100,000 gold.
It starts with 14 squares, and has to be upgraded the same as your first tab.
The Third tab cost 200,000 gold, and also has to be upgraded the same.

There are 3 tabs in total making it 210 squares.
The total cost for upgrading a tab is 40,000.
The total cost for everything is 420,000

*Please note, this was calculated during beta, so it is subject to change!*

[linky](http://www.diablowiki.net/Stash#Upgrading_the_Stash)